# Simple rvest code returning empty character

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the href from the 'Printer-Friendly Minutes' link on [this website](https://www.richmond.ca/cityhall/council/agendas/council/2021/012521_minutes.htm) using Selector gadget. Usually works, but this time I'm just getting an empty character in place of the href I'm trying to grab.

Here's the code:

```
url <- "http://www.richmond.ca/cityhall/council/agendas/council/2021/012521_minutes.htm"
try <- url %>% read_html %>% html_nodes(".first-child a") %>% html_attr("href")
```

Anyone know what might be going wrong?

Comment: If you view the source of the page, there is no class `first-child` being used. That value is probably added by javascript that runs on the page after it loads. `rvest` cannot run javascript. Make sure you look at the "Sources" tab to see what `rvest` can see, not the "Elements" tab. If you need to be able to run javascript to get the values you need, then you should look into using something like [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RSelenium) instead.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the distinction between Elements and Sources. In the Sources tab, 

I see the href that I want (href="/__shared/assets/PFM_CNCL_01252157630.pdf" target="_blank">Printer-Friendly Minutes</a></p>) - do you think I can somehow grab this using rvest, or would I still need to use RSelenium?

Comment: @MrFlick that's usually the case with such questions, but here the problem was just incorrect node selection. This one can all be done with static http methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have just not selected the node correctly. It's really helpful to learn xpath, which allows precise node navigation in html:

```r
library(rvest)

domain <- "http://www.richmond.ca" 

url <- paste0(domain, "/cityhall/council/agendas/council/2021/012521_minutes.htm")

pdf_url <- url %>% 
         read_html %>% 
         html_nodes(xpath = "//a[@title='PFM_CNCL_012521']") %>% 
         html_attr("href") %>%
         paste0(domain, .)

pdf_url
#> [1] "http://www.richmond.ca/__shared/assets/PFM_CNCL_01252157630.pdf"
```

We can see this is a valid link by GETting the result:

```
httr::GET(pdf_url)
#> Response [https://www.richmond.ca/__shared/assets/PFM_CNCL_01252157630.pdf]
#>   Date: 2021-10-18 20:35
#>   Status: 200
#>   Content-Type: application/pdf
#>   Size: 694 kB
#> <BINARY BODY>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked great. I had tried with xpath using selector gadget, but it didnt give me what you have above. Where did yuo find the appropriate xpath (or do you have resources to point me to RE: learning xpath?)

Answer (score 1):

As PFM is used as the abbreviation for the minutes you can target the href by that substring

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

url <- "http://www.richmond.ca/cityhall/council/agendas/council/2021/012521_minutes.htm"

read_html(url) %>% 
  html_element('[href*=PFM]') %>% 
  html_attr('href')
```

You could also use its adjacent sibling relationship to the preceeding`img` tag, which can be nicely targeted by its `alt` attribute value:

```
read_html(url) %>%
  html_element('[alt="PDF Document"] + a') %>%
  html_attr('href')
```